# StackOverflowException in mergesort code

Tags: vb.net, recursion, stack-overflow, mergesort

so I am currently doing A Level Computer Science and am coming to the end of my first year at college. As we only have 1 year left we have started our NEA project and in an attempt to start as early as possible I have started it now instead of in a months time, because I'm aiming for an A/A*. To give you some background information on the project I am doing, it will be a balloon tower defense style game coded in procedural VB.Net and to sort the scoreboard I am using merge sort which I have coded recursively (anything recursive gives extra marks). Just giving you a heads up now I am fairly new to coding and it has probably been made horrible, in all honesty I don't really know but just as a pre-warning

This is the entire Sort algorithm Code:

Highscore is a structure defined as an array with Score as Integer, and name as String.

```
Sub AddNewScore(ByRef HighScore() As Score)
    'ByVal NewScore As Score
    'Test Purposes only Remove for fullbuild
    Dim TempName As String
    Dim TempScore As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Name:")
    TempName = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Score")
    TempScore = Console.ReadLine

    If HighScore(9).Score < TempScore Then
        HighScore(9).Score = TempScore
        HighScore(9).Name = TempName
    End If
    'Test Purposes only Remove for fullbuild

    'If HighScore(9).Score < NewScore.Score Then
    'HighScore(9) = NewScore
    'End If
    MergeCore(HighScore)
End Sub
'Sorting Algorithm
Sub MergeCore(ByVal HighScore() As Score)
    Dim Left As Integer = 0
    Dim Right As Integer = 9
    Split(HighScore, 0, 9)
End Sub
Sub Split(ByRef HighScore() As Score, ByVal Left As Integer, ByVal Right As Integer)
    If Left < Right Then
        Dim Mid As Integer = (Left + Right) / 2
        Split(HighScore, Left, Mid)

        Split(HighScore, Mid + 1, Right)

        Merge(HighScore, Left, Mid, Right)
    End If

End Sub
Sub Merge(ByRef HighScore() As Score, ByVal Left As Integer, ByVal Mid As Integer, ByVal Right As Integer)
    Dim LSize As Integer = Mid - Left + 1
    Dim RSize As Integer = Right - Mid
    Dim LeftA(LSize) As Integer
    Dim RightA(RSize) As Integer
    Dim LPointer As Integer
    Dim RPointer As Integer
    For LP = 0 To LSize - 1
        LeftA(LP) = HighScore(Left + LP).Score
    Next
    For RP = 0 To RSize - 1
        RightA(RP) = HighScore(Mid + 1 + RP).Score
    Next
    LPointer = 0
    RPointer = 0
    Dim OriginalPointer As Integer = Left
    While LPointer < LSize And RPointer < RSize
        If LeftA(LPointer) <= RightA(RPointer) Then
            HighScore(OriginalPointer).Score = LeftA(LPointer)
            LPointer += 1
        Else
            HighScore(OriginalPointer).Score = RightA(RPointer)
            RPointer += 1
        End If
        OriginalPointer += 1
    End While
    While LPointer < LSize
        HighScore(OriginalPointer).Score = LeftA(LPointer)
        LPointer += 1
        OriginalPointer += 1
    End While
    While RPointer < RSize
        HighScore(OriginalPointer).Score = RightA(RPointer)
        RPointer += 1
        OriginalPointer += 1
    End While
    Console.WriteLine("ScoreBoard")
    For I = 0 To 9
        Console.WriteLine(HighScore(I).Name & " " & HighScore(I).Score)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
End Sub
End Module
```

The error (`"Exception of type System.StackOverFlowException has been thrown"`) is in the Sub Split line of this code:

```
   Sub Split(ByRef HighScore() As Score, ByVal Left As Integer, ByVal Right As 
  Integer)
    If Left < Right Then
        Dim Mid As Integer = (Left + Right) / 2
        Split(HighScore, Left, Mid)

        Split(HighScore, Mid + 1, Right)

        Merge(HighScore, Left, Mid, Right)
    End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated and any tips on anything else would be gratefully appreciated as well

Thanks

Comment: Turn Option Strict On in your project to see some problems that you're not aware of. The Mid calcullation seems suspicious. Then use the debugger to inspect values on the way down, since you have 10 items it should not be problem to trace it.

Comment: Because `Split` will keep calling itself. What exactly so you want to achieve with the `Split` sub?

Comment: ` / 2` does not do what you think it does.  That is a floating point division, the result has to be *rounded* to fit back into Integer.  Use ` \ 2` to get integer division.  If you still have trouble then add Debug.Print() statements so you can see the values of Left, Right and Mid.

Comment: Yeah It was the / 2 that was the problem, I cant believe something so simple flew straight over my head, Thanks